# Looking for free software to sign word documents

Tags: security, data-verification

I have a document which normally would be physically signed by two or more people. This document is internal use for the company I work for.

I'd like to do away with the physical signatures and what I'm looking for is some software that I can digitally sign and verify.

Word does this already, however, to get a CA cert involves money, and it's not a route I'd like to take. I can self sign the document, but anyone can create a self signature and there won't be a way to really verify which the real signature from the fake one unless someone notices and compares the two. However, I would prefer the CA root method because it ties very well with Word.

What I'm thinking about doing is is using gpg to sign the document (with a supervisor trust each person's gpg sig), and have each person sign the signature. More signature means more .sig files, and that's a pain but that's the only way I can think of / tried.

So what I'm looking for an application(s) that can multi sign and verify Word documents (bonus if it can PDFs too) but provide basic security a signature can be verified and compared to a trusted (within our network) sig / cert ?